# How to serve video to Roku Media Player?

Tags: software-recommendation, mediaserver, dlna, minidlna, rygel

I'd like to watch videos saved on my Ubuntu computer on my Roku. I've tried using [Rygel](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/rygel) and [MiniDLNA](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/minidlna) for this purpose. With Rygel, Roku Media Player will discover the videos but won't play them. With MiniDLNA, RMP can't even find the server.

Is there a configuration for one of these packages, or an alternative solution, which will allow me to watch this content in RMP?

Comment: I use the Plex Media Server.  I have been using the free edition for years.  You can pay for some more features for it, you can check into those on their site.  But for server / client, it has been great for me.  Just a suggestion.  https://www.plex.tv/

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. With MiniDLNA, it cannot find the server. I tried enabling logs and still no insight. It might be best with Plex.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience,you could maybe host a samba or network storage inside of ubuntu and directly access the videos from ubuntu Linux on your Roku player, as long as they are the right format (which could be converted using ffmpeg) ...like a nas